# Delete Dynamic rows Using ajax and laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have an Invoice, when I want to edit I want to able to delete some rows, either that row is found in DB or is added but click Add button. so I have to delete this row base on this conditions

1. Delete Row if is found in DB
2. Delete/Remove row if you added a new one(no need to check in DB, because you add new one)

Below is My invoice which show rows has data from DB and one which has not data (added new)
[image]

so I have done to delete the row which is found in DB, and I want to apply the second condition as per my below code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
              $("body").on("click",".remove",function(e){

              var last=$('#tdy tr').length;


              if(last==1){
                alert("you can not remove last row, Otherwise Delete The Order Number!");
              }

              //here i tried the second condition
               else if(iddata=null){


                $(this).parent().parent().remove();

                   }


                else{
                  if(!confirm("Do you really want to delete this?")) {
                   return false;
                 }

                 e.preventDefault();
            // var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var id = $(this).data("id");

            var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
            var url = e.target;

            $.ajax(
            {
                  url: "Loading/"+id, //or you can use url: "company/"+id,
                  type: 'DELETE',
                  data: {
                    "id": id,
                    "_token": token,
                  },
                  success: function (response){

                   if ( data['success'] ) 
                   {
                     alert(data['success']);
                     location.reload();
                   } 

                 }
               });
            return false;
          }

        });
```

how can i resolve this some can help me

Comment: More than code, I think you need architecture design or some better strategy.

Comment: Is that means i can not resolve this?

Comment: I advise you to format the code, it is easier to help you because it facilitates communication

Comment: @Mario, how do like me to format

Comment: Tools like https://prettier.io/ helps you to format js and also html, css, json. You can integrate tools like this to your IDE or text editor for example in my vscode instance I use Prettier - Code formatter https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: ok i will try this in my end, @Mario, but how can you assist me on my code

Comment: First fix this instead of `else if(iddata=null)` try ` else if(iddata === null)` or `else if(!iddatal)` try again and let me know

Comment: @Mario this correction is works thank you, but I want  to `refresh` a page after deleted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215758/discussion-between-mario-and-emma-mfinanga).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this

```
 else if(iddata = null)
```

For this

```
else if(iddata === null) // or else if(!iddata)
```

Here you need to use the equality operator [==](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) or even better the identity operator [===](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) instead of assignment operator [=](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment)

About reload the page when remove an item you can use

```
location.reload();
return false;
```

At the end of the function this because regardless of the type of deletion both operations end up refreshing the page